# Tengo un problema con mi sticky header

Tags: css

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi sticky header (encabezado pegajoso). Quiero que cuando bajes, dentro de la página, que mentenga la misma forma horizonal, que no se estire ni del lado izquierdo ni del derecho. Lo que pasa es esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando bajo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los códigos que estoy utilizando son estos:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;

 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if ( $(window).scrollTop() > altura ){
            $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed')
  } else {
   $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
* {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.contenedor {
 width: 95%;
 max-widht:1000px;
 margin: auto;
}

 .contenedor p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
 }

header nav {
 background:#eb374b;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
 -o-transition: all ease .5s;
 transition: all ease .5s;
}

 header nav ul {
  list-style:none;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

  header nav ul li {
   float: left;
  }

   header nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding: 20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
   }

   header nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #ed475a;
   }

.menu-fixed {
 position: fixed;
 z-index:1000;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.menu-fixed ul li a {
 padding:15px 20px;
}

.fuente {
 font-family: verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="contenedor">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XRdQ9Ub.png" alt="">
   </div>
   <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="fuente">
     <li><a href="#">Únete!</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Foro</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tienda</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Votar</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Soporte</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div class="contenedor">
  <p>
   1- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   2- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   3- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   4- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>
  <p>
   5- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   6- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   7- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   8- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>
  <p>
   9- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   10- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo hago para que cuando baje que no se achique? Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, ¿puedes proporcionarnos el código (HTML y CSS)? Si no, es imposible saber que puede estar fallando en tu página.

Comment: Listo Error404. Gracias por el aviso.

Comment: ¿Que navegador estas usando? A mí con Google Chrome me funciona perfectamente el código que has añadido. El menú ocupa el 100% del ancho de la pantalla.

Comment: Pero también utilizo un código JS
$(document).ready(function(){
 var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;

 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if ( $(window).scrollTop() > altura ){
            $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed')
  } else {
   $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
  }
 });
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quítale el `max-width` a tu clase `menu-fixed`. Además, tu clase `.contenedor` tiene un `max-width` mal escrito por lo que no se está aplicando esa clase, la he comentado también.

Por otro lado, el problema principal de tu pregunta es que el menú pasa a posicionarse como `fixed` y esto significa que ya no está en el "workflow" de la página, es decir, "es un elemento libre" y puedes posicionarlo donde quieras, ya que no depende de nadie.

Por eso, ya no toma el 95% de la anchura del contenedor, porque es un elemento independiente. Por eso, necesitas dotar al menú de las mismas propiedades que el `.contenedor`, con `margin: auto` y con anchura al 95% de la pantalla. Sin embargo, tendrás que añadir las propiedades `left: 0` y `right: 0` para este propósito.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;

 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if ( $(window).scrollTop() > altura ){
            $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed')
  } else {
   $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
* {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.contenedor {
 width: 95%;
 /* max-widht:1000px; */
 margin: auto;
}

 .contenedor p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
 }

header nav {
 background:#eb374b;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
 -o-transition: all ease .5s;
 transition: all ease .5s;
}

 header nav ul {
  list-style:none;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

  header nav ul li {
   float: left;
  }

   header nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding: 20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
   }

   header nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #ed475a;
   }

.menu-fixed {
 position: fixed;
 z-index:1000;
 top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
 width:95%;
    margin: auto;
 /* max-width: 1000px; */
 box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.menu-fixed ul li a {
 padding:15px 
      20px;
}

.fuente {
 font-family: verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="contenedor">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XRdQ9Ub.png" alt="">
   </div>
   <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="fuente">
     <li><a href="#">Únete!</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Foro</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tienda</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Votar</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Soporte</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div class="contenedor">
  <p>
   1- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   2- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   3- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   4- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>
  <p>
   5- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   6- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   7- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   8- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>
  <p>
   9- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>

  <p>
   10- Allahu Akbar juhasdguasdhiuasikdasdasbhj lmdsa bhkdas jlasknm dskjh klass dhuiasd kasnmbsi kdasn bdkha djkasnm dbasku diaj nsah dzasjk dnasd khasjkdasn kdhas djkaaskh ndjak nd hu kakasj aja jk hasi kja khasijkkj aska asjdkladjaskljddsa.
  </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Del lado derecho sí ocupa todo, pero del lado izquierdo sigue con el espacio.

Comment: @Nerraden ¿Osea quieres que ocupe 100% por ambos lados no?

Comment: En realidad no. Yo quiero que tenga de los dos lados unos 20 o 25px de margen, pero que no cambie, cuando cuando bajes y subas siga teniendo ese margen. En la primer foto del post tiene los margen bien, pero cuando bajo (la segunda foto) se deforma. Ese es el problema inicial. Yo quiero que baje y que tenga el margen a los costados. Pero que no se me achique todo el header.

Comment: @Nerraden Vale, ahora he entendido el problema realmente. Ahora edito la respuesta

Comment: Bueno, muchas gracias @Error404.

Comment: Cuando la hayas cambiado dime (actualmente sigue igual la web).

Comment: @Nerraden Ya está editada. Tu problema estaba con que los elementos fixed son considerados como elementos independientes. De todas formas, te lo he puesto en la explicación.

Comment: Listo @Error404. Ahora sí funciona bien. Muchas gracias por la ayuda y por ser paciente. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Dale un position: fixed; y width: 100%; al contenedor principal del header